# Any help for fix my access in web by localhost(path). It works by IP but not by localhost

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

By the problem I have, when I create chat and I put the code of send message I post the data like this:

```
function sendMessage()
{
    var text = $('#text').val();

    if (text.length > 0)
    {
        $.post('http://localhost/chats/public/sendMessage', {text: text, username: username}, function()
        {
            $('#chat-window').append('<br><div style="text-align: right">'+text+'</div><br>');
            $('#text').val('');
            notTyping();
        });
    }
```

I think that the problem is for posting data by path.

Comment: which Operating System are you using ? windows ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply avoid putting the domain for the request if the Javascript runs on the same domain.

```
$.post('/chats/public/sendMessage', {text: text, username: username}, function()
{
    $('#chat-window').append('<br><div style="text-align: right">'+text+'</div><br>');
    $('#text').val('');
    notTyping();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (text.length > 0)
    {
        $.post('<?php echo URL::asset("chats/public/sendMessage");?>', {text: text, username: username}, function()
        {
            $('#chat-window').append('<br><div style="text-align: right">'+text+'</div><br>');
            $('#text').val('');
            notTyping();
        });
    }
```

You can use url like this

```
<?php echo URL::asset("/chats/public/sendMessage");?>
```

and use this class in aliases which is located in config/app.php

```
'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
```